# Unable to run Stencil Locally

Tags: node.js, git-bash, bigcommerce, config.json

I have followed all the steps to integrate stencil locally but I am facing an issue on running it locally. http://localhost:3000/ isn't redirecting.

Whereas when I am trying to insert URL directly it shows me the error page of my theme.

Here is a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/66b7g.png

Comment: What format is the URL in? Are you using a relative path or something else?

Comment: I just followed all the steps which where listed here. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/running-stencil-locally. I tried inserting this URL to my browser http://localhost:3000/  and its displaying an error message. Am I missing out something?

Comment: So it isn't loading locally, rather than it isn't redirecting?

Comment: which command are you using to trigger the server? and what server? Did you check to start a script with npm that runs node?, I was facing the issue that node wasn't responding when using stencil dev server